# How to create pageview overlapping effect?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to create an overlapping pageview collection, but because of draw/layout order of items the second page always shows up in front of first page. There a way to create a collection list that the first items overlapping the others?

```dart
PAGE BUILDER ->

 Widget buildList(PreloadPageController pageController, List data,
      double currentPosition) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 12.0 / 15.0,
      child: PreloadPageView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        controller: pageController,
        preloadPagesCount: 2,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CardWidget(
              page: index,
              currentPage: currentPosition,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }


CARD WIDGET ->
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, contraints) {
      final double padding = 20.0;

      var delta = currentPage - page;
      var start = padding * delta.abs() * 10;

      var top = padding + padding * max(-delta, 0.0);
      var bottom = padding + padding * max(-delta, 0.0);

      //print(start);
      return Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(-start, 0),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: top, bottom: bottom),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
            child: Container(
              color: _randomColor(page),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

I was expecting create a collection effect so the second page would come from behind the first one, but actually second pages always appears overlapping the first. 
I could use `reverse` in PageView.builder, but this collection needs to be a infinity list that loads more data when it reaches the end and with `reverse` the code will be alot trickier.

I'm achieving this:

[image: wrong result]

But what I want is the blue card behind the red one.

Comment: Try using Stack widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: Hi! U said use Stack rather then PageView? I tried, but using Stack widget I have a giant memory overheap consumption causing app crash when it starts to load more data.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I ended up using reverse property of PageView.builder, but I had to give up from an endless scroll pages.

Answer (score 1):

So right now, to create your overlapping effect, you are offsetting the *next*-Page so that it overlaps the *cur*-Page, and as you mentioned, you discover that the *next*-Page visually *over-laps* instead of the desired *under-lap*.

Then, in additional to your offset, have you tried cropping off the overlapping portion of *next*-Page? This can simulate the effect of *under-lapping*.

Now, I tried replicating your sample, but I'm uncertain about your `PreloadPageController` (and maybe other details), so my sample might look glitchy. Additionally, I'm not wholly familiar with cropping widgets. But I bumped into this possible solution, all I did was wrap it with another `ClipRect`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final double padding = 20.0;

      var delta = widget.currentPage - widget.myPage;
      var start = padding * delta.abs() * 10;

      var top = padding + padding * max(-delta, 0.0);
      var bottom = padding + padding * max(-delta, 0.0);

      return ClipRect(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(-start, 0),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: top, bottom: bottom),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
              child: Container(
                color: redOrBlue(widget.myPage),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

This additional `ClipRect` basically clips off your offset portion. Feel free to explore and modify as needed!

[image]

Comment: Hi, I try out your solution, but what it does is crop card behind first pageview and since my implementation makes card moves apart from pageview it creates a gap between frist and second card (cropping the second one).

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Overlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) widget but it may cause more headaches, especially at scale. You can wrap your pages in a `ClipRect`, but only the widgets at the end of the list will need it. So in the builder function, set up a bool:

```
clipNeeded = (controller.page + 0.5) <= index;
```

Then in the new ClipRect widget:

```
clipper: clipNeeded ? CustomRect() : null,
```

Then you'll need to create that `CustomRect` class, extending `CustomClipper<Rect>`

The exact math required depends on the implementation, but in this left to right scroll example, it'll be something like

```
class CustomRect extends CustomClipper<Rect>{

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    double leftLine = /* some calculation */;
    return Rect.fromLTRB(leftLine, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomRect oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```